# Error in React typecript : 'string' can't be used to index type

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I have a DetailPage component
and I have JSON data called `data.json`
and data structure example like this:

```js
data = {
  mobile: [...someData], speaker:[...someData],
  ... and ....
}
```

My problem is about using `useParams` hook and I want to use params as key of object like this:

```js
import data from "../data/data.json";

const DetailPage = () => {
  const { category, id } = useParams();
  return <h1>{data[category][id].title}</h1>;
};
export default DetailPage;
```

The first error is:

```
Type 'undefined' cannot be used as an index type.
```

I solve that with typeguard condition in inline jsx:

```
<h1>category !== undefined && data[category][id].title</h1>
```

But the second error I can't handle:

```
Element implicitly has an 'any' type
  because expression of type 'string' can't be used to index type
```

Comment: What is the inferred type for `data`?

Comment: Looks like it should be `useParams<keyof typeof data>()`. That's usually bad code but I think this react API requires it.